# Retrieve data from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Below is a sample xml file with the data i'm after

```
<ns2:Response/">
<cacheKey>-7ca7484a:13e22cb1399:-47c0</cacheKey>
<cacheLocation>10.186.168.39:7302</cacheLocation>
</ns2:Response>
```

I have 2 classes, 1 class for getting xml data, this class then passes the data to another class that will have many other classes which extract the data.

```
public static string GetXmlData()
{
    string xmlPath = "url";
    var wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/xml");
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/xml");
    var xmlData = wc.DownloadString(new Uri(xmlPath));

    var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);

    return xmlDoc.ToString();
}
```

The second clas has the following

```
public class GetCacheKey
{
    public string cacheKey { get; set; }
}
```

Below is where I'm having problem:

```
public IEnumerable<GetCacheKey> CacheKey()
{
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(GetXMLData());
    var xkey = from c in doc.Descendants("Response")
                select new GetCacheKey()
                    {
                        cacheKey = (string)doc.Element("cacheKey").Value  
                    };

    return xkey;
}
```

In debugger, it returns Empty = "Enumeration yielded no results"

So how can I get the value of cacheKey?

Comment: Don't you mean `c.Element("cacheKey").Value` ?

Comment: Hi @Thorarin that did not work, I think the problem is with <ns2:Response/"> I'm just after the data of <cacheKey> at the moment

Comment: `<ns2:Response/">`  Why does an opening tag contain a `/`? Why is a `"` there?

Comment: Hi @I4V i do not know, this is how it is complete, with url removed <ns2:Response xmlns:ns2="http://somesite.com/">

Comment: It looks like you left the /" from the URL string in there.  You should remove it if you removed the rest of the xmlns attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually two problems with your code. First of all, `doc.Descendants("Response")` will not yield any results, because you've omitted the `ns2` bit. Secondly, `doc.Element("cacheKey").Value` should be `c.Element("cacheKey").Value`:

```
XNamespace ns2 = "http://namespaceurihere";

var xkey = from c in doc.Descendants(ns2 + "Response")
           select new GetCacheKey()
           {
               cacheKey = c.Element("cacheKey").Value
           };
```

Not really an issue, but the string cast in your code was redundant.

The namespace URI should be whatever URI you removed from the XML when you edited it for posting. It confuses people however, because `<ns2:Response/">` is not valid XML.

Comment: Hi @Thorarin almost there, I now get System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,Web.UI.Controllers.HomeController+GetCacheKey] returned on page, and yes it was a typo, end of url

Comment: Ok got it working now var p = CacheKey().FirstOrDefault().cacheKey; returns the value

Comment: Thank you all and Thorarin, learning all this coding is a challange at time